# Как в PHP вывести сумму товаров с MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, мне нужно подсчитать сумму(цену) товара в бд за определенную дату.

Сейчас вывожу сумму цен всех товаров, а нужно по дате (в коде за дату 13.03.2017).

Делал вот так но не получается, ибо выводим сумму всех товаров

```
$vivod = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `date`, `name`, SUM(price) as sum FROM `orders` WHERE paid = '1' AND fund = 'QIWI'");

   while ($ss = mysql_fetch_assoc($vivod)) {

  $yesterday1 = "13.03.2017";

  $v1 = date("d.m.Y", $ss['date']);

  if($v1 === $yesterday1) {
    echo $ss['sum'] + 0;
  }
```

Comment: Дак  а в чем проблема в запросе поле даты указать как условие?

Comment: @Oma В базе они хранятся в стиле майсклюли, то есть сохраняется вся дата например "22.03.2017 18:40" и как я буду делать выборку? Придется считать под каждую секунду что ли

Comment: Ну так то есть функции которые вытаскивают только дату =)

Comment: @Oma не понял, что вы имеете ввиду ?

Comment: Вот https://sevidi.ru/php/phppage45.php и вот http://webi.ru/webi_articles/8_15_f.html Первые ссылки в гугле, читайте на здоровье.

Comment: `where date_time_column>='2017-03-13' and date_time_column<'2017-03-13'-interval 1 day`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Группируем данные по дате и наименованию товара(`GROUP BY`):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`id`) as ids, DATE(`date`), `name`, SUM(price) as sum 
FROM `orders` 
WHERE paid = '1' AND fund = 'QIWI'
GROUP BY DATE(`date`), name
```

Также получаем список id заказов в каждой группе через запятую
*(Агрегатная функция `GROUP_CONCAT`)*

---

Выбираем данные за нужную дату:

```
SELECT `id`, `date`, `name`, SUM(price) as sum 
FROM `orders` 
WHERE paid = '1' AND fund = 'QIWI'
  AND DATE(`date`) = '2017-03-13'
```